# How to avoid line insert to the file if the line is already present in the file?

Tags: algorithm, perl, syntax

How should the check be made so that there are no line duplicates in the file

```
open ( FILE, ">newfile");
for( $a = 1; $a < 20; $a = $a + 1 ) {
    my $random_number = 1+ int rand(10);;
    # check to avoid inserting the line if the line is already present in the file
    print FILE "Random number is $random_number \n";
}

close(FILE);
```

Comment: `//` does not create a comment in Perl. It is an operator.

Comment: Are you trying to create a list of 20 unique random numbers? Because that is not obvious from the way you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!$seen{$_}++` is a common idiom for identifying duplicates.

```perl
my %seen;
for (1..19) { 
    my $random_number = 1+ int rand(10);

    say "Random number is $random_number" if !$seen{$random_number}++;
}
```

But that doesn't guarantee that you will get all numbers from 1 to 10 in random order. If that's what you are trying to achieve, the following is a far better solution:

```perl
use List::Util qw( shuffle );

say "Random number is $_" for shuffle 1..10;
```

Comment: This will give a list with an inconsistent number of elements. If for example all random numbers turn out to be 10, only 1 line is printed.

Comment: @TLP, Yes, that is what the OP asked for, and that's what the first snippet does. But that's probably not what they wanted, thus the second snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Enter each line into a hash as well, what makes it easy and efficient to later check for it

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $filename = shift or die "Usage: $0 filename\n";

open my $fh, '>', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

my %existing_lines;

for my $i (1..19) 
{ 
    my $random_number = 1 + int rand(10);

    # Check to avoid inserting the line if it is already in the file
    if (not exists $existing_lines{$random_number}) { 
        say $fh "Random number is $random_number";
        $existing_lines{$random_number} = 1;
    }   
}
close $fh;
```

This assumes that the intent in the question is to not repeat that  number (symbolizing content to be stored without repetition).

But if it is indeed the whole line (sentence) to be avoided, where that random number is used merely to make each line different, then use the whole line for the key

```
for my $i (1..19) 
{ 
    my $random_number = 1 + int rand(10);
    my $line = "Random number is $random_number";

    # Check to avoid inserting the line if it is already in the file
    if (not exists $existing_lines{$line}) { 
        say $fh $line;
        $existing_lines{$line} = 1;
    }   
}
```

Notes and literature

- Lexical filehandles (`my $fh`) are much better than globs (`FILE`), and the three-argument `open` is better. See the quide [perlopentut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut) and reference [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open)
- Always check the `open` call (`or die...` above).  It can and does  fail -- *quietly*. In that check always print the error for which it failed, [$!](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$!)
- The C-style `for` loop is very rarely needed while the usual `foreach` (with synonym `for`) is much nicer to use; see it [in perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops). The `..` is the [range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Range-Operators)
- Always declare variables with [my](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my), and enforce that with [strict](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict) pragma; *always* use [warnings](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/warnings)
- If the filehandle refers to pipe-open (not the case here) always check its [close](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close)
- See [perlintro](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro#Hashes) for a general overview and [for hashes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro#Hashes); for more about Perl's data types see [perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata). Keep in mind for later the notion of complex data structures, [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you are asking is how to randomize the order of the numbers 1 to 20. I.e. no duplicates, random order. That can be easily done with a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). For example:

```
perl -le'print for map { $_->[0] } sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } map { [$_, rand()] } 1..20'
6
7
16
14
5
20
3
13
19
17
4
8
15
10
9
11
18
1
2
12
```

In this case, reading from the end and backwards, we create a list of numbers 1 .. 20, we feed that into a `map` statement which turns each number into an array-ref, containing the number, and a random number. Then we feed that list of array refs to a sort, where we sort numerically on the second argument in the array ref: the random number (hence creating a random order). Then we transform the array ref back into a simple number with another `map` statement. Finally we print the list using a `for` loop.

So in your case, the code would look something like:

```
print "Random number is: $_\n" for      # print each number
    map { $_>[0] }                      # restore to a number
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }        # sort the list on the random number
    map { [ $_, rand() ] }              # create array ref with random number as index
    1 .. 20;                            # create list of numbers to randomize order of
```

Then you can use the program like below to redirect output to a file:

```
$ perl numbers.pl > newfile.txt
```

Comment: That's an expensive way to shuffle a list, though not an issue for such a small list. But it's also very complicated compared to using existing `shuffle`. (And you somehow changed 1..10 to 1..20?)

Comment: Where do you see `1..10`? Yes, `shuffle` might be more appropriate. Though I don't know how `shuffle`'s code looks.

Comment: Re "**Where do you see 1..10?*" `1+ int rand(10)` only produces numbers from 1 to 10 incl. // Re "*I don't know how shuffle's code looks.*", It's a Fisher-Yates shuffle. (Swap a random element for the current one, shift out the current one, repeat for the rest. Effectively, keep picking a random element from those that left.)